# Как получить доступ к переменным/функциям, определенным в другом пакете

Tags: golang

Есть такая структура приложения

```
./
├── conf
│   └── conf.go
├── helpers
│   └── helpers.go
├── config.cfg
└── main.go
```

в main.go:

```
import (
   "./conf"
   "./helpers"
   "fmt"
   ...
)
var cfg conf.Config
func init() {
   cfg = make(conf.Config)
   cfg.Parse("config.cfg")
}
func main () {
   fmt.Print(cfg["variable"])
}
```

В /helpers/helpers.go хочу использовать `cfg` :

```
func Helper() {
   fmt.Print(cfg["variable"])
}
```

Но при компиляции получаю ожидаемую ошибку `helpers/helpers.go:10: undefined: cfg`.
Как мне получить доступ к `cfg` в helpers/helpers.go ?

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя импортировать имена из пакета `main`.

Переменная `cfg` должна быть в одном из пакетов-библиотек, например `conf`, тогда к ней можно будет обратиться как `conf.Cfg`.

Также импортируемые имена должны начинаться с большой буквы, т.е. `Cfg`.

Comment: То-есть мне нужно `conf` импортировать в helpers? И вообще  в каждый пакет, где я захочу получить доступ к конфигу?

Comment: это печально. То-есть никакой "нисходящей" области видимости нет?

Answer (score 1):

Вышел из положения следующим образом:

conf/conf.go:

```
type ConfigType map[string]string
var Config ConfigType
```

main.go:

```
//var cfg conf.Config
func init() {
   conf.Config = make(conf.ConfigType)
   conf.Config.Parse("config.cfg")
}
func main () {
   fmt.Print(conf.Config["variable"])
}
```

helpers/helpers.go:

```
import "../conf"
func Helper() {
   fmt.Print(conf.Config["variable"])
}
```

Вроде как работает. Но - насколько это хорошее решение? Наверняка есть альтернатива.

Answer (score 0):

У тебя неправильный подход.

Все файлы пакета должны находиться на одном уровне вложенности (в одной папке), создание подпапки, означает что это уже совсем другой пакет.

```
./
├── conf.go
├── helpers.go
├── config.cfg
└── main.go
```

Используя такую структуру все переменные (экспортируемые или нет) будет видны во всех файлах пакета.

Если же ты действительно хочешь создать пакет для конфигурирования твоей программы и пакет хелперов, то да создавай подпапки, но правильнее их будет тогда называть плагинами/драйверами и при импорте *они* сами должны регистрироваться через init, а уже main выбирать из доступных.

conf/conf.go:

```
type ConfigType map[string]string

type Config{
    conf ConfigType
}

func init() {
    conf := make(conf.ConfigType)
    // Заполнить conf по вкусу

    driver.Register("mysql", &driver.Driver{
        Config: conf,
    })
}
```

main.go:

```
var (
    drivers   = make(map[string]driver.Driver)
)

func UseConfig(driverName) conf.Config {
   return drivers[driverName].Config
}

func main () {
    conf := UseConfig("mysql")
    fmt.Print(conf["variable"])
}
```

Пример [driver](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/driver/), например, для sql.

Comment: если все держать в одном каталоге - как тогда импортировать все эти пакеты в main.go?

Comment: если все в одной директории, то их не надо импортировать ни в main.go, ни в какой либо другой файл в этой директории, можно сразу использовать, просто обращаешься по имени. Тесты например, если создать файл main_test.go, то в нем будут доступны все что доступно в main.go и наоборот.

Comment: `ls test/  
main.go  
mytype.go`  
  
в **mytype.go**:  
`package mytype  
type TT struct {..some..}`  
  
в **main.go**:  
`var mt mytype.TT`  
**./main.go: undefined: mytype in mytype.TT**  
  
в **main.go**:  
`var mt TT`  
**./main.go: undefined: TT**

Comment: разобрался вроде